# Using Cloudformation with a Chef Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, aws-cloudformation, disaster-recovery

I'm exploring some disaster recovery scenarios and how to comeback from them quickly. Disasters like our root AWS account being hacked, or all of Oregon going down. Basically situations where we need to recreate our entire infrastructure in another region or account.

Obviously Cloudformation is the best way to tackle this, but I have some questions on how to integrate it with Chef. My plan is to have a CF script create a new Chef server as well as all the other servers, then the Chef server pulls all it's cookbooks from a repository and configures all the servers. Is this a reasonable process or is there a better way to handle it?

I figured this was better than maintaining AMIs specific to applications and copying those over.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Chef has a [chef-server cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef-server) that will provision a stand-alone instance. I'm actually writing a wrapper for it now as I'm dealing with the same situation.

Our plan is similar to yours but we're using Terraform to orchestrate the environments.

Have a repository of cookbooks gzipped and ready for deployment. After provisioning and configuring the Chef server, deploy said cookbooks to it.  The Chef server would need to be fully bootstrapped with all cookbooks, environment configs, and data bags before attempting to create any other nodes. Once complete, bootstrapping the rest of the environment would look like any other deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the information! That's helpful. That's pretty much how I was thinking it would go. I would be interested to see your wrapper once you finish it.   How do you like Terraform?   I really liked it when I was comparing it with CF, but I ended up with CF because it seems to support AWS a little better than TF and supports new services much quicker. (obviously since it's created AWS)